# How to pythonically add one argument to the url of all calls using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, decorator

I'm using the Python [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library to call an API, and I want to append an argument (`&t=abcd`) to every request I make. I can of course make a function like this:

```
import requests
def callTheApi(url):
    return requests.get(url, params={'t': 'abcd'})
```

but somehow I have the idea that there's a cleaner and more pythonic way to do this, maybe using a decorator or something. Does anybody know how?

Comment: Have you considered `functools.partial`, or just a simple wrapper function?

Comment: Do you mean by append that there might be other get params as well?

Comment: Sure, you may reassign `requests.get = my_decorator(requests.get)`, but sample from your question is much more reasonable. Re-binding another function to de-facto standard library would mislead anyone that reads a code, and will mislead them hugely. First of all - explicit is better than implicit. Second of all, any additional code that uses requests and would not require this extra parameter will simply break.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
import requests    
call_the_api = partial(requests.get, params={"t": "abcd"}))
call_the_api(url)
```

You can also pass additional keyword arguments to extend/override the initial ones, e.g.:

```
call_the_api(url, params={"t": "efgh"})
```